# warning: arithmetic between different enumeration types (x and y) is deprecated How closed?

Tags: makefile, enums, clang, warnings, cflags

I just want to turn off the warning below.
other warnings should remain open.

Clang 11

warning: arithmetic between different enumeration types (x and y) is deprecated

Makefile ?

CFLAGS = ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add code makefile
CFLAGS += -Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion

and fixed

sorry very easy problem :D